# Remote application start

Tags: software, streaming

So, I'm abroad and I want to stream my music library, I use [subsonic](http://www.subsonic.org/pages/index.jsp) on my main desktop (iMac) to stream music to my MacBook Air. So far it's been working fine, but it seems that the subsonic application on iMac has stopped working. The problem is with subsonic only, I can still access my shared files etc.

Is there a way to restart subsonic remotely? I tried to do shared screen but I don't seem to find the right menu for that.

Comment: How remotely? Is the iMac abroad? Also, what do you mean by "the right menu"?

Comment: Yup, I'm a thousand miles away right now. I remember that there was a button for screen sharing, maybe in finder, but for some reason I can't find it right now.

Comment: What ports do you have open on your iMac? Do you have port 22 (ssh) open?

Comment: I think it's open.

Comment: Open Terminal and type `ssh [your_username]@[imac_web_ip]` and press enter. If it asks you to allow an encryption code, type `yes` and press enter, then enter your username and password.

Comment: To answer your question about screen sharing, if the computer that you want to access is in the Finder sidebar under "Shared", select it and there should be a "Share Screen" button on a black bar near the top of the Finder window.

Comment: Matt, how do I find out what my iMac ip is?
Nathan, the computer is under shared and I can access my files, but there is no share screen button.

Comment: @user20997 If there is no Share Screen button, then screen sharing is not available for the remote Mac.  Explains why you couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

The screen sharing button you mentioned is located in Finder. If you turned on `Back to My Mac` on your iMac the iMac should show up in the Finder's sidebar. Click on the iMac's icon and you get the screen sharing button.

Alternatively if you know the IP address or URL: In Finder press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> and type in `/System/Library/CoreServices/` to navigate to the place where the screen sharing application is located. Open screen sharing and type in the address of your iMac and connect.